# Probably a combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

Given an alphabet consisting of the two letters $A$ and $B$, find the number of strings of given length that can be formed such that the string contains at least one set of three consecutive $B$'s.

Comment: Do you mean an alphabet consisting of the two letters A and B?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ which contain three consecutive $B$s. If $n\geq 3$ then such strings may end in 4 distinct ways: $A$, $AB$,  $ABB$, $BBB$.

Therefore  $x_n$ is equal the number of strings of length $n-1$ that contain three consecutive $B$s with an $A$ at the end *plus* the number of strings of length $n-2$ with three consecutive $B$s with a $AB$ at the end *plus* the number of strings of length $n-3$ with  three consecutive $B$s with $ABB$ at the end *plus* the
number of strings of length $n-3$ with $BBB$ at the end. Hence we have the recurrence,
$$x_n=x_{n-1}+x_{n-2}+x_{n-3}+2^{n-3}.$$
Note that $x_0=x_1=x_2=0$. The first terms of the sequence are:
$$0,0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 20, 47, 107, 238, 520, 1121, 2391, 5056, 10616, 22159.$$

Comment: @Appoose M Divakaran "Excuse me, but can we include strings of length $n−3$, with ABA at the end?" No, they are already counted  by the strings of length $n−1$ that contain three consecutive $B$s with an $A$ at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to have a two-letters alphabet $\{A,B\}$, then the number of strings of length $k$ with at least one set of three consecutive B's is $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{k-3}2^i}$. The idea would be to move the string of consecutive B's around and think about the possibilities in each position, without repeating.